# Intramolecular Claisen-Condensation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

My task was to do an intramolecular Claisen condensation with this molecule.

[image]

I already draw the product to the reaction, but I'm not sure, if I did it right. Could anyone help me out or confirm the solution? There should be only one product since there is symmetry.

Here is the way how I got the product in my question:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want ChemSE to provide reagents or a mechanism? If so, let's see what you think. Then help will be offered. In any case, welcome to ChemSE! Your question will likely be considered as homework. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself or, at least, make some effort. Take a look here about homework policy. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange

Comment: @user55119 I want to know if the product, which I got is right.

Comment: It is necessary to show how you got the product in your question. So, we may able to see you are in right path or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way how I got the product in my question:

[image]

Comment: Looks all right to me... I think this is called 'Dieckmann condensation'.

Comment: Maybe a couple of hints for further reflection: 1) do you think the product you drew may react further in the reaction environment (sodium ethoxide etc)? 2) what stops the initial deprotonated intermediate from undergoing retro-Michael?

Comment: @user6376297 1) the beta carbon of the product is actually well sheilded by the carbonyl , ester and geometry of the six membered ring so it will be very sterically costly to react at this center 2) I think amine group is a very bad leaving group so retro-michael is not much preferred

Comment: The mechanism you have drawn is catalytic in base. However, the Dieckmann reaction is stoichiometric in base. Why?

Comment: Did you just made a different account for writing an answer? If so, request the mods to merge both the accounts.

Comment: @user55119 : that was the point of my question 1 :)